# How to send timezone value with UTC for a Rest Request

Tags: java, rest-assured, jackson-databind

I'm testing a Rest service with Rest Assured using Jackson for parsing the Json.

For a particular service request I need to send a **fieldName** named **deliveryDate** (In UI user selects the date via a datepicker).

The request payload is like this **`"deliveryDate":"2022-02-15T22:00:00.000Z"`**. This is how the corresponding payload from the browser console looks too.

I change the date to the current date retaining the same format for the test run but the test returns a **HTTP 500** with the following stackTrace `org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Client time zone not specified!`

So how should I resolve this issue. Also my current time zone is UTC+2:00.

Comment: What are your Java and Jackson versions?

Comment: Try the next date formats:

Date Time with Offset -  '2011-12-03T10:15:30+02:00'; 

Zoned Date Time - '2011-12-03T10:15:30+02:00[Europe/Riga]'; 

According to documentation: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

Comment: My Java version is 8 and Jackson is 2+@VostanAzatyan